# Fancontrol service wont start, configuration file broken

Tags: 22.04, fancontrol

I have been trying to setup fancontrol on my XPS 17.
I am running **Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS**

Now here is my config file :

```
# Configuration file for fancontrol
INTERVAL=2
DEVPATH=/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon7
DEVNAME=dell_smm
FCTEMPS=hwmon7/pwm1=hwmon7/temp1_input hwmon7/pwm2=hwmon7/temp1_input
FCFANS=hwmon7/pwm1=hwmon7/fan1_input hwmon7/pwm2=hwmon7/fan2_input
MINTEMP=hwmon7/pwm1=20 hwmon7/pwm2=20
MAXTEMP=hwmon7/pwm1=60 hwmon7/pwm2=60
MINSTART=hwmon7/pwm1=150 hwmon7/pwm2=150
MINSTOP=hwmon7/pwm1=20 hwmon7/pwm2=20
MINPWM=20
MAXPWM=255
```

Now when trying to restart the service I get this error :

```
janv. 13 00:47:51 dellxps fancontrol[6143]: Device path of /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon7 has changed
janv. 13 00:47:51 dellxps fancontrol[6143]: Device name of dell_smm has changed
janv. 13 00:47:51 dellxps fancontrol[6143]: Configuration appears to be outdated, please run pwmconfi>
```

Again checking with `fancontrol --configure`

```
fancontrol --configure
Loading configuration from /etc/fancontrol ...

Common settings:
  INTERVAL=2

Settings for hwmon7/pwm1:
  Depends on hwmon7/temp1_input
  Controls hwmon7/fan1_input
  MINTEMP=20
  MAXTEMP=60
  MINSTART=150
  MINSTOP=20
  MINPWM=0
  MAXPWM=255
  AVERAGE=1

Settings for hwmon7/pwm2:
  Depends on hwmon7/temp1_input
  Controls hwmon7/fan2_input
  MINTEMP=20
  MAXTEMP=60
  MINSTART=150
  MINSTOP=20
  MINPWM=0
  MAXPWM=255
  AVERAGE=1

Device path of /sys/class/hwmon/hwmon7 has changed
Device name of dell_smm has changed
Configuration appears to be outdated, please run pwmconfig again
```

I don't understand the error, I have checked and nothing has changed.

Comment: if you add or remove any hardware, the hwmon # may change.  This should easily be solved with `pwmconfig`